# Run js after display template has loaded/rendered content

Tags: javascript, display-template

I have a javascript file that I want to run after my display template has rendered.
I have added it to my display template like so :

```
<script>
$includeLanguageScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Language Files/{Locale}/CustomStrings.js");
$includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Customfeedbackinbox.js");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display templates support OnPostRender event hanlder. You can invoke the JavaScript function using this

```
ctx.OnPostRender.push(ctx, function () {
    InvokeFunctions();
});
```

An excellent article [Useful JavaScript to know when working with SharePoint Display Templates](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2014/02/26/useful-javascript-for-working-with-sharepoint-display-templates-spc3000-spc14.aspx)

Comment: the same functionality can be achieved using this AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function () {     // do something
});